# UTF-8 Encoding in R

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, readr

I work on a windows computer and have problems to encode german "umlaute" (special characters like äÄöÖüÜ). When I open scripts my coworkers write on their Macs I need to change these characters all bei hand because otherwise the scripts won't work. 
Further I can't access variables that contain those characters. 
I use readr's read_csv() to read in data, which has UFT-8 as default so I do not understand why this happens. 
I have also tried to change the encoding of the csv. with visual studio code to UFT-8 but this doesn't work either. This problem only occurs inside R.

Can someone help me on this issue, because I am really annoyed by this issue.

Comment: Is the CSV from an excel file?

Comment: Yes it is a .csv